# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException reading image as byte []

Tags: java, image

I'm trying to take a png image file made through RServe, convert 'raw' binary to byte [], and create Buffered Image to display within a JFrame via JLabel icon. The following code works fine for one type of image that I'm making, but not for another.

```
REXP xp = c.eval("r=readBin(" + imageFileSelect + ",'raw',800*800)");
        c.eval( "unlink(" + imageFileSelect + "); r");
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(xp.asBytes());
        BufferedImage buffered = ImageIO.read(in);
        Image rescale = buffered.getScaledInstance(800,800, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel();
        picLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(775,775));
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(rescale);
        picLabel.setIcon(icon);
```

Using .available() on the InputStream for the working image gives ~350,000. Using the same command on the image that doesn't work I get 650,000 and the BufferedImage is never made. My questions: 1) is the .available() command telling me the size of the InputStream I'm making so the image that isn't working is ~2x the size? 2) is there a size limit to my code that's not allowing the second image to be made, or is there another error that I'm not seeing?

Alternatively, if use the following code to create my image icon I receive the included error.

```
Image img =  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(xp.asBytes());
Image rescale = img.getScaledInstance(750,750, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

Uncaught error fetching image:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at sun.awt.image.PNGFilterInputStream.read(PNGImageDecoder.java:828)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:238)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(PNGImageDecoder.java:364)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:269)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
*
```

Comment: is this some strange kind of format that you are trying? should be gif jpg png bmp

Comment: The image is being made in RServe as a bitmap. So within the Rserve session I'm taking the file out as raw binary and converting it to bytes. I tried  reading the file directly with ImageIO.read(filename) but that doesn't work. Unless there is a way to make the image in Rserve and save it in a temporary Java location. I have a version of the program that automatically saves the image to the Desktop. But not i'm trying to make it more dynamic and not print the image until the user wants to.

Comment: This is what Im focusing on: "The following code works fine for one type of image that I'm making, but not for another. " what is that type of image that it works, is it png, bmp,  some other? If the reader doesnt have a header info it wont be able to read the raw bytes.

Comment: ok it is created as bits, always in the same way, but sometimes it is accepted by java sometimes it is not, is what I'm getting. Maybe you need to clarify your pipeline, what those bits are where they are coming from -

Comment: Above i wrote bitmap when i meant png sorry. The image that works is a line plot created within RServe as a png. The second image is also a png but it is a plot made by the package RCircos. These images are more complicated than the line plot, but still a png. So both images come from different plotting functions within R

Comment: you can check if buffered is null; if it is then Circos doesnt deliver the bytes appropriately; if buffered is not null but rescale is null then getScaledInstance doesnt work

Comment: I added the following code to check if the bufferedImage is null. `BufferedImage buffered = ImageIO.read(in);
     
     if(buffered == null){
            System.out.println("image is null");
            } else {
            System.out.println("image: " + buffered.getHeight() + "," + buffered.getWidth());   
            }` There is no output from this code leading me to believe my code is  getting bogged down in in writing to the buffered image. is there a way to make this part of the code "better" or test this hypothesis?